# What are the steps involved in creating a Tensorflow.lite model?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

***What are the steps involved in creating and training a Tensorflow model to use in an Android app ?***

Below is what I think needs to be done in my scenario (based on what I've researched)

- I know I need to gather training images of various car parts and label them using  labelImg . Then split into training and testing folders.
- Create and train the model .
- Export it to a .tflite format to later be used in the Android app.

Questions.

- What resources can/should I use ?
- The biggest one would be, what coding examples or coding resources should I follow to create the TF Model ?

**I would highly appreciate being pointed in the right direction as to where I should start.**

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:
Can I write the above training model in Python locally on my PC or do I have to use Google colab?
--> You can try both seperately, both work.
What resources can/should I use ?
--> If your refering to GPU you can use that through colab [runtime->change runtime->hardware/device and GPU]
The biggest one would be, what coding examples or coding resources should I follow to create the TF Model ?
-->Please refer to this link and let us know [https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples]